# Filter CSV file and create a new file with filtered rows

Tags: windows, csv, powershell

I am looking to filter rows by the description column. I want to filter out all rows that contain 'Free WiFi' and then create a csv file and make it comma separated.

```
HOTELID|AMENITYCODE|DESCRIPTION
722602|8|24-hour front desk
722602|109|Air conditioning
722602|23|Dry cleaning
722602|81|Fax/photocopying
722602|107|Free WiFi
723303|11|Fitness centre
723303|107|Free WiFi
723303|205|Fruits
723303|79|Hammam
723303|80|Heating
723303|44|Ironing service
723303|176|Kid meals
```

What shell/Java/C# script can I use in order to do this and be used by a task scheduler in Windows.

Thanks,
Spencer

Comment: note the S.O. definition of the `[shell]` tag. You probably want either `[batch-file]` or `[Powershell]` instead. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a PowerShell pipeline like this

```
Import-Csv .\input.txt -Delimiter '|' | ? { $_.Description -notlike '*Free Wifi*' } | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation processed.csv
```

where `input.txt` is your input file and `processed.csv` will contain your new CSV without the WiFi stuff.

Comment: It makes me sad every day that "NoTypeInformation" isn't the default. Now it's a breaking change to fix it, and MS is unlikely to ship a breaking change.

Comment: Yup maybe it was by design to have a nice example / reason to have $PSDefaultParameterValues :)

Answer (score 0):

In basic Java we can do with the below code:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String readFile = "C:\\test.txt";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = "\\|";
        String filter1="Free WiFi";
        List<String[]> output = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        String writeFile = "C:\\testout.csv";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readFile))) {
            output.add(0, br.readLine().split(cvsSplitBy));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] input = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                if(input[2].contains(filter1)) {
                    output.add(input);
                }  
            }

            File file = new File(writeFile);
            FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter(file);
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile); 
            writer.writeAll(output); 
            writer.close();
            System.out.println("Program ended");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```